SecRuleEngine: deprecatevar not working
I am trying to use SecRuleEngine for rate limiting. I get the 429 after 5 requests but it never works again and returns to 200. I am trying to reduce the count every 10 seconds with deprecatevar.
SecRuleEngine On
<Location "/">
SecAction "id:9001,phase:1,nolog,pass,initcol:ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR},setvar:ip.requests=0"
SecAction "id:9002,phase:2,nolog,pass,setvar:ip.requests=+1"
SecRule IP:REQUESTS "@gt 5" "id:9003,phase:2,deny,status:429,setenv:RATELIMITED"
SecAction "id:9004,phase:4,nolog,pass,deprecatevar:ip.requests=1/10"
</Location>

It seems a very basic example, so I must be missing something?

In case anyone is interested:
The issue for me was I was running inside a docker container and the actual IP was not in REMOTE_ADDR. Often it is in X_FORWARDED_FOR but in my case, it was X_CLIENT_IP. You need to figure out your possible trusted proxies and use mod_remoteip to transfer the IP address to REMOTE_ADDR. RemoteIPHeader tells mod_remoteip where to look for the actual IP.
LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so

RemoteIPHeader X-Client-IP
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 169.254.0.0/16

mod_remoteip seems to be able to prevent spoofing of IPs.
